# Do JanusGraph Cassandra Indexes Need To Be Reindexed?

Tags: gremlin, cassandra-3.0, janusgraph, tinkerpop3, java-17

Do JanusGraph indices need to be reindexed after loading in more data?

I know this is a newbie question, but I am a newbie with on this subject. 
From my understanding right now, OrientDB and Neo4j don't; and I think most SQL database servers default to automatically self-govern their own maintenance. But, I just want to make sure I'm testing JanusGraph correctly when I'm checking its performance.

I didn't find [JanusGraph Docs](https://docs.janusgraph.org/master/interactions/transactions/) telling me it explicitly does-or-does-not upkeep its indexes;
Nor did I see [JanusGraph](https://docs.janusgraph.org/schema/index-management/index-lifecycle/) showing me sample indexing output and logs.
And I especially don't know if the behavior would change from using [`"inmemory"`](https://docs.janusgraph.org/storage-backend/inmemorybackend/) compared to [backend-server Cassandra](https://docs.janusgraph.org/storage-backend/cassandra/) being used instead.
Plus, some examples use [Oracle Berkeley DB](https://docs.janusgraph.org/storage-backend/bdb/) which leaves me more uncertain about backend-server specific concerns.

```java
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Vertex;
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraph;
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory;
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphVertex;
import org.janusgraph.core.PropertyKey;
import org.janusgraph.core.schema.JanusGraphManagement;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JanusGraph janusGraph = JanusGraphFactory.build().set("storage.backend", "cql").set("storage.hostname", "localhost:9042").open();
        JanusGraphManagement janusGraphManagement = janusGraph.openManagement();
        PropertyKey propertyKey = janusGraphManagement.getOrCreatePropertyKey("_id");
        if (!janusGraphManagement.containsGraphIndex("_id"))
            janusGraphManagement.buildIndex("_id", Vertex.class).addKey(propertyKey).buildCompositeIndex();
        janusGraphManagement.commit();
        JanusGraphVertex janusGraphVertex = janusGraph.addVertex();
        janusGraphVertex.property("test","test");
        janusGraph.tx().commit();
        janusGraphVertex = janusGraph.addVertex();
        janusGraphVertex.property("test","test2");
        janusGraph.tx().commit();
        janusGraph.close();
    }
}
```

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>janusgraph-cql</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create the keys and labels you want to index in the same transaction as you create the index, there is no need to re-index.

If you need to pickup anything created prior to creating the index, you need to perform the re-index steps.

Once that is done and the transaction committed you should be able to start adding data and write queries that utilize the index(es) you created.

Ending a Gremlin query with `.profile()` will show you which (if any) index the query runtime used to help execute the query.

The easiest way to experiment with this is to use the `inmemory` graph and launch it from the Gremlin console using:

```
gremlin> g=JanusGraphFactory.open('inmemory').traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[standardjanusgraph[inmemory:[127.0.0.1]], standard]
```